# Specifying several markers at once in pyplot.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw a plot with 2 lines with `pyplot.plot`. Is there any way to specify several markers at once?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[0, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
plt.plot(c, marker = 'o') # the two lines will have the marker, which I don't want.
plt.show()
```

I know I can loop around the lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
markers = ['*', 'D']
for i in range(len(data[0])): plt.plot(map(list, zip(*data))[i], marker = markers[i])    
plt.show()
```

but I wonder if there exist a better solution, e.g. one that would look like `plt.plot(c, marker = ('*', 'D'))`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the specific syntax you are looking for exists. I think it introduces too many ambiguities and probably violates the Python principal ['explicit is better than implicit'](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

You can do this,

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    

data = np.array([[0, 0],
                 [1, 2],
                 [1, 3],
                 [1, 4]])

plt.plot(data[:,0], '*-', data[:, 1], 'D-')
```

Honestly though, I don't really feel that this is 'better' than a loop.

Comment: Thanks, right  I had forgotten to mention this solution, but I agree not really better :)